# jQuery unable to render html to be used by Underscores's template

Tags: jquery, underscore.js

I have made two files, one for HTML where a script is defined with the id='search_template' and another javaScript file were I have mentioned the "View".

In the render function of View, I am picking up the script in HTML file with

> id='search_template'

using jQuery and passing it through the jQuery's

> .html()

to convert it into String and then passing it to Underscores's

> _.template ( String )

However, Underscore throws an error

*Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'replace' of null*

I believe jQuery is unable to convert the script with the id='search_template' to String.

```
SearchView = Backbone.View.extend({
      initialize: function(){
        _.bindAll(this, 'render');
      },
      render: function(){
        var template = _.template($("#search_template").html());
        $("body").html(template);
      }
    });
var search_view = new SearchView({ el: $("#search_container") });
    search_view.render();
```

I removed the jQuery part from the render  function and tried by explicitly passing the HTML string without using the .html() function:-

```
render: function(){
    var template = _.template("<label><%= search_label %></label> 
    <input type=\"text\" id=\"search_input\" /> 
    <input type=\"button\" id=\"search_button\" value=\"Search\" />");
    $("body").html(template);
}
```

And this works perfectly fine.
Why is it not working when I am using jQuery to pick up the script using $("search_template").
Also when I merge both HTML and JavaScript file it works.
Here is a snippet from HTML file :-

```
<script type="text/template" id="search_template">
<label>Search here : </label>
<input type="text" id="search_input" />
<input type="button" id="search_button" value="Search" />
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

This `render`:

```
render: function(){
  var template = _.template($("#search_template").html());
  $("body").html(template);
}
```

isn't working because you don't have a `#search_template` in the DOM when it is called. Here's some proof if you don't believe me: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/HFYyx/

You have a typo or a sequence issue somewhere:

1. If you're not including `#search_template` in the HTML, then fix the HTML.
2. If you're running `render` before `#search_template` is in the DOM, then put your `render` call in a `$(function() { ... })` wrapper so that it won't be called until the DOM is ready.
3. If you have typo in the `id`, then fix your typo.

Those would be the most common causes of your problem.

---

As an aside, [`_.template`](http://underscorejs.org/#template) returns a function (unless you also pass it the second argument):

> **template** `_.template(templateString, [data], [settings])`
>
> Compiles JavaScript templates into functions that can be evaluated for rendering.
>   [...]
>   If you're writing a one-off, you can pass the **data** object as the second parameter to template in order to render immediately instead of returning a template function.

so you should be calling `template` and using its return value as HTML:

```
$('body').html(template());
// --------------------^^
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to pass an object along with template call:

```
var template = _.template($("#search_template").html(), { search_label: "Label1" });
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
$(function() {
    var search_view = new SearchView({ el: $("#search_container") });
    search_view.render();
}
```